# GX23-2 Lampholder removing wires without cutting

Tags: electrical

An existing lamp holder has cracked and will not hold a lamp. How can I remove the existing broken lamp holder without cutting wires? The pictures are of one I can cannibalize.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't. I would just cut them back an inch or two on both the bad one and the "donor", then use splices on the wires.

Answer (score 0):

They are generally soldered on. The 2nd picture shows the plastic covers, which push in, which inside is where the wires are soldered on. You'll need to find a way to pull these out. Once they are out you can melt the solder with a soldering iron to remove the wires.